# Supermicro X7DBU, how to put it to sleep

Tags: linux, electrical-power, opensuse, supermicro

I am very new to server administration and just learning the stuff. I have just inherited a Supermicro 1U Server X7DBU running openSuse 12.3. Is it possible to configure it to go to sleep or low power mode after some period of inactivity? Is it a linux operation or server configuration?

Comment: Why do you want a server to go into sleep mode? This is a pretty unusual configuration.

Comment: See, the thing about servers is... they're supposed to serve things.  Typically 24/7.  So generally, you don't want them going to sleep, though with most modern ones, you can limit their power consumption, though again, a feature I find to be of dubious value, and one that causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: @MDMarra it is a test server that I use it once in a while to run some simulations

Comment: @HopelessN00b it is just sitting there and consuming power uselessly most of the time which is what bothers me. If I could, I would like to curtail that purposeless consumption.

Comment: The problem is that every on/off cycle increases wear and tear of your server much more than steady-state running.

Comment: For part-time operation, consider running a virtual machine on some other server that is continuously used instead.

Comment: The server supports Wake-On-LAN, you could enable that to be able to remotely turn it on when you're using it, and have a crontab that shuts down the machine if it's been inactive for some period of time.

Answer (score 4):

Turn the server off when you're not using it. Turn it on when you need it.

For your purposes, you don't have any practical deep-sleep options for that Supermicro hardware that would be substantially better than poweroff/poewron.

There are exceptions to this... [Look into the ACPI modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface#Power_states) (especially S3 or S5) and `acpitool`.

For Linux, `acpitool -s`.

Comment: +1 That's what I do now :) leaving it on for weekends. But want to leave the question open a little bit just in case someone could help me configure it for step down power usage.

Comment: @Dinesh See the `acpitool` command...